# Analizando Server Errors con .NET

Tags: asp.net, genexus

Trabajando con .net c#, a veces es necesario analizar los archivos .cs generados para identificar dónde se pueden estar dando los errores:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tomando como ejemplo la imagen anterior, el error se encuentra dentro de la subrutina S1172() en el archivo periodico.cs:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora, ¿qué es lo que significan los "+1963"?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Cuando agregues còdigo no lo agregues como imagen por favor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Son indicadores de desplazamiento dentro del código ensamblado...   no indica nada contra el código fuente..  pero al menos podes acercarte al lugar del error viendo el nombre del procedimiento tal como lo buscaste...

Aquí lo explica con un ejemplo similar:
https://odetocode.com/Blogs/scott/archive/2005/01/25/funny-numbers-in-my-stack-trace.aspx

Comment: Gracias por tu contribuciòn, te sugerimos revisar [answer], revisa lo relacionado a los enlaces, saludos.